# Javascript to enable/disable asp DropDownList showing funky behaviour?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am disabling a dropdownlist when a button is clicked

```
function disableDropDown(DropDownID)
{
  document.getElementById(DropDownID).disabled = true;
  return false; <---------tried with and without this, no luck
}
```

and a onClick call to

```
disableDropDown('DropDownID');
```

I see it disable the dropdown and then immediately there is a postback happening which enables it back. Can someone explain what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is an ASP.NET Button control calling it? That's probably why your page is posting back.

Try just using a regular html input button.

`<input type="button" onclick="disableDropDown('DropDownID');" />`

Comment: I think the asp.net button control contains a OnClientClick parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you might have this attached to an `asp:Button` which is posting back.

All you really need is an `<input type="button">` or even just a `<button>` element

```
<button onclick="disableDropDown(DropDownID);">Disable DropDown</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function EnableDisableControl(source, Chk, ddl) 
{
    if (source.checked == false) {
        document.getElementById(ddl).selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById(source.id.replace(Chk, ddl)).disabled = !source.checked;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(source.id.replace(Chk, ddl)).disabled = !source.checked;
    }
}
```